# Transposing specific number of rows in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering it is possible to transpose a specific number of columns in a single column and display it in a row. For example, if there was a column that extended from A1 to A1000000, is it is possible to select the first 272 data points and then transpose it into a single row starting at A1 and then select the next 272 rows and display it on B1 etc. until it reaches the last row.

Thanks,

Comment: I just undeleted it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Sub CopyToRange()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim Cnt As Long, i As Long, j As Integer
    Dim n As Long

    Set rngDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    vDB = rngDB

    Cnt = 272

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1) Step Cnt
        n = n + 1
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To Cnt, 1 To n)
        For j = 1 To Cnt
            If i + j - 1 > UBound(vDB, 1) Then GoTo p
            vR(j, n) = vDB(i + j - 1, 1)
        Next j
    Next i
p:
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n, Cnt) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)


End Sub
```

Comment: If I didn't want to transpose the data, what would the script look like then?

Comment: @nekmat97, Range("a1").Resize(n, Cnt) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)   chage to  Range("a1").Resize(Cnt, n) = vR

Answer (score 1):

Select A1:A272. Press Copy (or Ctl+C).
Select B1. Press `Paste` in the top left corner of the ribbon's `Home` tab.
Select `Paste Special` and `Transpose` in the dialog box that opens.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I originally tried but there's 30 million data points so it would take me forever to do it this way.

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Transp_mod2()

Dim P1 As Range, T2()

Set P1 = Sheets(3).UsedRange 'Adapt to your source column range
T1 = P1

Rws = P1.Count
Rmd = Rws
Spl = 272 'Adapt to your required steps
Cnt = 1

If Rws Mod Spl = 0 Then Rnds = Rws / Spl Else Rnds = Int(Rws / Spl) + 1

For i = 1 To Rnds
    ReDim Preserve T2(1 To Spl, 1 To i)
    If Rmd = Rws Mod Spl Then t = Rmd Else t = Spl
    For j = 1 To t
        T2(j, i) = T1(Cnt, 1)
        Cnt = Cnt + 1
        Rmd = Rmd - 1
    Next j
Next i

Sheets(4).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(T2, 2), UBound(T2, 1)) = Application.Transpose(T2) 'Adapt "Sheets(4).range("A1")" to your destination range

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I try running it after editing the parts I have to change but I get an error for this line "T2(j, I) = T1(Cnt, 1)". The error is 'Run-time error '13': Type mistmatch'"
Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I was not able to replicate your error. You could have this on the transpose line if any of your cells has more than 255 characters but not there. My best guess is that it has to do with your data... anything special about it ?

Comment: The data is normal, it's just a column with many rows. The code you sent afterwards worked fine. Thank you so much!